# Removing washing paint stains from clothes

Tags: washing-machine, paint-removal, removal, stain-removal

As house windows and doors was being painted by enamyl paint got paint stains on clothes how  can we remove wash or remove paint stains

The paint stain has been dried

tried white vinegar baking soda detergent hot water  tarpine oil kerosine oil thinner

There are many favorate clothes of family members and many places drops stains where many places drops stains  I want some solution chemical oil which I can soak the clothes in so that the paint stain can dissolve without harming clothes

Advice and helpful suggestions are thanful

Comment: When painting, folks generally wear clothing that it doesn't matter if they get stained or not as it's difficult to impossible to remove paint stains from most clothing.  Either you will damage the clothing or find that you cannot remove the stain completely.  I suggest that you may just want to "retire" the stained clothing and use them the next time you are painting.

Answer (score 2):

### It's over.

They are beyond saving.  There was a chance when it was very fresh and wet, and if you started with the right thing (paint thinner) as mentioned on the paint can's label.  But once it dries, or you set it with the wrong chemical, *it's all over but the shouting*.

Why were you in fresh paint areas anyway? Stay away.